# Rounding towards zero on a PDL

Tags: perl, rounding, pdl

I have a PDL (type `double`) of mixed values (both positive and negative). I want to round each entry towards zero.
So `+1.2` becomes `+1`, `+1.7` becomes `+1`, `-1.2` becomes `-1`, and `-1.7` becomes `-1`,

I thought of using `int()`, but it doesn't work on PDL types.

I can also use `round(abs($x) - 0.5) * ($x <=> 0)`, but not sure how to use this logic on a PDL.

Pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of the `rint` function in [PDL::Math](http://p3rl.org/PDL::Math) says:

> If you want to round half-integers away from zero, try `floor(abs($x)+0.5)*($x<=>0)`.

Just change it slightly to make it work the way you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use PDL;

my $pdl = 'PDL'->new(
    [  1,  1.3,  1.9,  2,  2.1,  2.7 ],
    [ -1, -1.3, -1.9, -2, -2.1, -2.7 ]
);
$pdl = floor(abs($pdl)) * ($pdl <=> 0);
print $pdl;
```

Output:

```
[
 [ 1  1  1  2  2  2]
 [-1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2]
]
```

Comment: @KoshVery: Updated, that was related to an older version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

[PDL::Math](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Math) has `floor`, `ceil`, and `rint`. All these functions work in place.

Therefore, something like the following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use PDL;

my $pdl = 'PDL'->new(
    [  1,  1.3,  1.9,  2,  2.1,  2.7 ],
    [ -1, -1.3, -1.9, -2, -2.1, -2.7 ]
);

print $pdl;

floor(inplace $pdl->where($pdl >= 0));
ceil (inplace $pdl->where($pdl <  0));

print $pdl;
```

Output:

```
[
 [   1  1.3  1.9    2  2.1  2.7]
 [  -1 -1.3 -1.9   -2 -2.1 -2.7]
]

[
 [ 1  1  1  2  2  2]
 [-1 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2]
]
```

PS: @choroba's answer seems to run about 20% faster in the following benchmark with non-threaded `perl` 5.24 on [an ancient MacBook Pro](https://www.nu42.com/2017/01/mid-2010-macbookpro-new-battery.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use constant N_ELEMS => $ARGV[0] || 100_000;

use Dumbbench;
use PDL;

sub one_scan {
    my $pdl = 100 * grandom(N_ELEMS);
    $pdl = floor(abs($pdl)) * ($pdl <=> 0);
    return;
}

sub two_scans {
    my $pdl = 100 * grandom(N_ELEMS);
    floor(inplace $pdl->where($pdl >= 0));
    ceil (inplace $pdl->where($pdl <  0));
    return;
}

sub baseline {
    my $pdl = 100 * grandom(N_ELEMS);
    return;
}

my $bench = Dumbbench->new;

$bench->add_instances(
    Dumbbench::Instance::PerlSub->new(code => \&baseline,  name => 'Baseline'),
    Dumbbench::Instance::PerlSub->new(code => \&one_scan,  name => 'One Scan'),
    Dumbbench::Instance::PerlSub->new(code => \&two_scans, name => 'Two Scans'),
);

$bench->run;
$bench->report;
```

Comment: I am looking to round the values towards zero, not away from it. Also, if my pdl variable is `$myPDL`, how will I use `abs()` and `<=>`? Will the `$x` become `$myPdl` instead, with the function being applied to each entry in the PDL automatically?

Comment: In the condition `($x >= 0)`, `$x` is an individual variable. How do I make this check for each entry in the PDL and then go for either `floor()` or `ceil()`?

Comment: Should the statement be `($myPdl >= 0) ? floor($myPdl) : ceil($myPdl);` and it will do it for all the entries?

Comment: @choroba `floor()` will not round *towards* zero. Will fail for, say, `-12.2`

Comment: @CinCout: That's why there's `abs`. See my reply.